# PC restarts (specially at games)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu, reboot

I have updated my PC drivers by EasyDriver software and updated my windows 10 about 2 weeks age. The app updated all drivers and PC restarted to apply updates. after that my PC reboots, specially at gaming (games loading screen) without any error or BSOD.
other than gaming, PC restarts rarely.

What I did to solve the problem:

-Installed a fresh win 10 
-Downgraded and upgraded GPU Driver versions
-Uninstalled GPU Driver by DDU and installed fresh GPU driver
-Checked CPU fan and GPU connections
-Disconnected DVD/CD RW to reduce electricity consumption (If the problem related to PSU)

but none of the above helped.
when I disable my Display adapter (GPU Driver) at Device Manager, PC not reboots anymore!

My PC specs:
Intel core i5-2400 , 12GB Ram , ATI HD 7790 , 2 HDD , MSI PH61A-P35 mainboard and a 530 watt PSU.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess the PSU isn't powerful enough and/or you have overheating issues. Disconnecting a drive that isn't being used does nothing.

Comment: but I'm using my PC for years with this PSU and didn't have any problem before updates

Comment: "For years" means the PSU is less than 80% efficient compared to when it was new. But of course Windows Updates can also play a part. You need to do some tests. It's nothing that can be solved here.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  what kind of tests?